# Location of npm CA cert

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm

We have a corporate mandated SSL MITM and I'm trying to get `npm` to play nicely with it. With no configuration, `npm install` produces

```
$ npm install --verbose
...
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 12:21:46
npm verb etag "BHYPP2OQ6VBKY2B3TPXTCBVRQ"
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
...
```

When I put our [custom SSL pem in ~/.npmrc](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#ca)

```
ca="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n..."
```

I get the following

```
$ npm install --verbose
...
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/time-grunt
npm verb request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm verb request no auth needed
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 12:27:17
npm verb etag "BHYPP2OQ6VBKY2B3TPXTCBVRQ"
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/request
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames
npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames
...
```

Which, if I understand correctly, is `npm` using that one SSL certificate as the only root CA, which would make sense why it wouldn't work. Short of bloating the `~/.npmrc` with a `ca[]="-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n..."` line for every CA, is there a single `certs.pem` file I can append our internal pem to?

I'm looking for something similar to the way I got homebrew installed applications to work correctly with

```
cat internal-cert.pem >> /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
```

I hope there's something similar for npm/node.

Comment: Have you tried [`cafile`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#cafile)?

Comment: Thanks @Kenan, I hadn't seen that setting. I set the cafile to my system cert.pem but I'm still getting `npm info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: Hostname/IP doesn't match certificate's altnames` unfortunately.

Comment: Shoot :( I thought it might exhibit a different behavior from `ca`

Comment: Was definitely worth a shot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the strict-ssl flag. I had a similar issue before.

`npm config set strict-ssl false`

I actually took the cert out of my ~/.npmrc , but not sure if you leave it in if it will affect anything.

Comment: Right, I forgot about [that option](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#strict-ssl). I was hoping I could keep verifying SSL certificates but just add our existing cert to the cert chain.